# How do disk encryption programs solve the "IV problem"?

Tags: disk-encryption, truecrypt

I was reading a [paper on the "elephant diffuser" used in BitLocker](http://css.csail.mit.edu/6.858/2009/readings/bitlocker.pdf) and it got me wondering how other systems (e.g. TrueCrypt before it shutdown) solved the problem the elephant diffuser was meant to solve; namely that there isn't enough space on a disk block to store an IV.  Where is the IV stored in other systems or do they have alternative solutions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is not to store an IV but to store an authentication tag.

I don't know about any other products that solve this problem in a way similar to BitLocker. [LUKS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Unified_Key_Setup) uses XTS by default, and TrueCrypt supported LRW and XTS, among other modes. Neither of these two modes provide any diffusion. Information about various modes for disk encryption is available [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_encryption_theory).

Answer (score 1):

The IV is not stored in other systems. Apart from using XTS (which truecrypt uses), other disk encryption software typically use ESSIV to dynamically create a unique IV for each sector and this is what is used by bitlocker as well.. The initialization vector of the AES-CBC is determined by AES-ECB encrypting the sector offset with the FVEK. The sector offset is a 16-byte little-endian version of the offset of the sector relative from the start of the volume and this guarantees the uniqueness of the resulting iv. Diffuser targets a different problem..